# Cursor position not same after remove text in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm looking for solution for this problem. I want my cursor to be at the starting position normally.

I have a **UITextView**, which the users can input a message and send it.
But when users send the message, or they just remove the text in **UITextView**, the beginning of the cursor(blinking bar) is not the same position, the position depends on the length of the text they had sent or removed. If the text is only 1 line, the cursor position will be in the top left corner of **UITextView**, otherwise, if the text is longer than 1 line, the cursor position will be in the bottom left corner of **UITextView**.

I tried both **setMarkedText** after **becomeFirstResponder()** and **automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets** but it still not work.

**More Info:**

In the first time touch in this UITextView, the cursor jumps from center vertically to top left corner too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a UILabel over the UITextView which will act as a placeholder for the textView. When user taps on the UILabel would send the action to the textView and makes it becomeFirstResponder. When you start typing, make the label hidden.